# Ajax Post Form - Difficulty Integrating XHR2 File Upload

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, upload, xmlhttprequest

I've searched around stackoverflow and google and found plenty of material on the subject, but non of which is helping me grasp what I'm trying to achieve.

I'm trying to create a form which asynchronously sends form data and uploads a single image, resizing, renaming and saving it to a specified directory though the same php script.

Everything works perfectly if sending the data in the traditional way.

Where I'm coming unstuck is when trying to integrate the XHR into the existing jQuery which handles the non-file form data, and sending that file to the PHP script along with everything else.

I'm not particularly well versed in JS, I'm very much in a state of learning. Everything I've found so far has been in the form of examples for uploading only files, focusing on upload progress, multiple file upload and drag'n'drop (which I'm not interested in for this project).

I'm not a fan of copying code and trying to botch it to work with what I've written, I'd rather understand how to do it...

Has anyone come across any reading material/tutorials which demonstrate and explain how to implement an ajax file upload within a standard ajax form post?

Thanks in advance.

---

Simplified example of the code I'm working with:

```
<script>

$('#editgig_form').submit(function(){

    $('#ng_loading').fadeIn(500);

    var eg_dataString = $('#editgig_form').serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Resorces/Components/GigDiary/edit_gig.php",
        data: eg_dataString,
        success: function(){

        $('#giglist_canvas').load('Resorces/Components/GigDiary/refresh.php');

        $('#ng_loading').fadeOut(500);
        popupclose(edit_gig);                   
        editmenu_selected = '';
        }

    });

return false;

});

</script>
```

-

```
<form id="editgig_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="date" />
    <input type="text" name="venue" />
    <input type="file" name="image" />
</form>
```

-

```
<?php

date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['date']));
venue = $_POST['venue'];

// SCRIPT TO RESIZE IMAGE, SAVE TO DIRECTORY 

$update = "UPDATE gigdairy SET date="$date", venue="$venue", image="imgname";
mysql_query($update);

?>
```

Comment: show some code what have you tried?

Comment: I've not _tried_ to implement this, as I really don't know where to start with it. I'll add a snipped of what I have to illustrate what I'm trying to do.

Comment: ok then you need to use this class new XMLHttpRequest().upload in your ajax call uploading via ajax with xhr2 it depends upon browser other wise you have to upload with traditional way. Hope it make sense...

Comment: Thanks, this is the conclusion that I'd come to. Browser isn't an issue, as all users are on Chrome. Implementing it is where I'm falling down as I'm not sure how it works. ie. does this allow the file to be passes to the PHP? Or does this additional javascript upload the file, following which a different piece of PHP would have to access the saved file and resize it.

Comment: one more question.... your traditional way means refresh the page to save? Just for sake of my surity so I can answer properly.

Comment: Correct. Apologies for my not-very-professional terminology :)

Comment: ok then go for this link it is for valums-ajax-upload- it is a js file try to understand it it has a very understanding coding. Implement it in your local environment here is the link.https://github.com/valums/file-uploader/blob/master/client/fileuploader.js hope it helps if want some code help then let me know so I can post it in as a answer coz I implement it in my local environment and it is very handy among all from past.

Comment: Thanks you! I'll give this a try and post the outcome.

Comment: @Rajat Modi - Thanks for the link you provided. I reviewed the example and found it to be quite elaborate considering the simplicity of what what I wish to use it for. I've opted to use the 'hidden iframe' method which is working quite effectively. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to print the datas you are sending (`console.log` in your browser or `var_dump($_FILES)`in your php)? I know you're just post the name of your file.

You will need to implement this functionality (the file upload), or you can use a jquery plugin for that like plupload, HTML5 File Uploads ...

Code example here
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/